# x-editable refresh loading the data-source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

```
<a class="javascript-file-set editable editable-click" data-name="jsFileId_<?=$i?>" data-value="0" data-pk="" data-source="/asset/getClientScriptAssets" data-type="select" href="#">Not Specified</a>
```

I've integrated an uploader button with the x-editable popover, thus when the user uploads files they get appended to the list generated from the data source.

Unfortunately when calling the display callback the new <option> elements in the <select> list do not show up in the sourceData argument. A simple solution would be to simply reload the data source. How to do this without creating a new x-editable object? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like my solution is the sourceCache option.

Don't know how I missed it. You guys woulda had an easy 50 reputation, tisk.